# How do you send JSON objects from JavaScript to a C# server?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, kinect, p2p

Is there a way to send the JSON objects from JavaScript to a C# server using Peer to Peer network? Or if there is there any other method of sending the data in real-time onto a C#. Both my function from my JavaScript Code are listed below.

Peer To Peer Code

```
function newPeerServer(evt) {
    console.log('Creating new peer server');
    newPeerEntry = true;
    evt.preventDefault();
    myPeerId = document.getElementById('newpeerid').value;
    var peerNetTemp = document.getElementById('peernet').value;
    peerNet = JSON.parse(peerNetTemp);

    // Distroy default peer before creating new one
    peer.disconnect();
    peer.destroy();

    // Show new peer credentials. Hide default ip address
    document.getElementById("connectionopen").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("newpeercreated").style.display = 'block';
}

function sendToPeer(evt, data) {
    var dataToSend = {"event": evt, "data": data};
    peer_connections.forEach(function(connection) {
        connection.send(dataToSend);
    });
}
```

Skelton Tracking Code

```
function startSkeletonTracking() {
    console.log('starting skeleton');

    var skeletonCanvas = document.getElementById('skeleton-canvas');
    var skeletonContext = skeletonCanvas.getContext('2d');

    resetCanvas('depth');
    canvasState = 'depth';

    if(kinect.open()) {
        kinect.on('bodyFrame', function(bodyFrame){
            if(sendAllBodies) {
                sendToPeer('bodyFrame', bodyFrame);
                if (doRecord) {
                    bodyFrame.record_startime = recordStartTime;
                    bodyFrame.record_timestamp = Date.now() - recordStartTime;
                    bodyChunks.push(bodyFrame);
                }
            }
        });
        kinect.openBodyReader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript, as in used the browser for security reasons has no direct file access,  `other than AJAX`,  `fetch` or `websockets`

Comment: Ah okay thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax, which is simplified even further using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'your-url-to-csharp-method-here',
    data: {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Jeff',
        age: 33
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

There are other ways of passing data (such as websockets), but I don't see a reason to use anything other than AJAX for passing JSON to a server.

Comment: Where does this code belong in the C# server or the JavaScript code that is sending the data? Also what would go on the URL and do I put the various joint whose data the JavaScript code is collecting and I want to send over to the server?

Comment: This is the javascript code that calls the server. The way the url works with ajax is the actual `url` key in that code in my answer is not the full url. It gets fully generated using the `data` key. For example, if the url was `https://stackoverflow.com` and the data key contained `id: 3`, the full url will become `https://stackoverflow.com?id=3`

Comment: To answer your question further, to get the actual url you simply take the domain name, and the route to your method. e.g. if your domain is `https://helpme.com`, and your route to the method is in the `Helpers` directory, and your method is called `GetMyData`, the base url would be `https://helpme.com/Helpers/GetMyData`